# How to pin Touch Keyboard in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, touch-keyboard

I can open the following touch keyboard in Windows 10

[image]

I am using the label to open it, by moving the mouse and clicking, but then, when a physical keyboard is used, the tough one disappear. So I need to click the button again and again.

Is there any way to pin this keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the following steps:

1. Go to Settings
2. Ease of Access
3. Keyboard
4. Select the **Use  the On-Screen Keyboard** option:

> [image]

The keyboard should now be pinned on the screen

Comment: This doesn't work for TOUCH keyboard.